# How to make bootstrap-ui datepicker and timepicker be inline?

Tags: angular, datepicker, timepicker, bootstrap-ui

Is there a way to make bootstrap-ui components appear inline, like so:
[image]

I have tried various things but I can't get them all to align. Here is the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XMXmKIKBpE01n4tjb4k3?p=preview)

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
       <div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></div>
    </p>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Have tried changing the uib-timepicker tag from `div` to `span`, but that breaks the datepicker component: https://plnkr.co/edit/CjBzCthVyoQAVooi5oR7?p=preview

**UPDATE2:**
To calrify, this question is about this library: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

**UPDATE3:**
Updated the plunkr provided in the accepted answer with relative units: https://plnkr.co/edit/TaoVJZwCjh1uLyz3huk9?p=preview

Comment: atleast give your full code !!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh it is in Plunkr

Comment: i cant understand the code but did you used display:inline block??

Comment: take the full bootstraps datetimepicker instead!!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh. I have updated the question to clarify what we are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the last `div` tag to `span` tag.
- Add two new CSS classes:

  - .buttonClass{ vertical-align:top; }
  - .timeClass table:first-child { top:-35px; position:relative; }
- Add button class to `span` which holds the button,
- Add time class to `span` that holds time picker.

Comment: Thank you, but it appears to break the datepicker component: https://plnkr.co/edit/CjBzCthVyoQAVooi5oR7?p=preview

Comment: That is just CSS style thing, I have updated the answer. https://plnkr.co/edit/Zb32Ica32DHUKH6dVVOe?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, but still doesn't work. I have updated the Plunkr with your recommendations and the result is the same. Can you modify the Plunkr so that it gives the correct result please?

Comment: Did you try plunker which I provided, it should work? You probably forgot the first step.

Comment: What you did wrong is applied timeClass with the dot, please remove the dot in that span where you are applying this class: (<span class=".timeClass"... but without the dot.

Comment: Sorry, it's not the dot: https://imgur.com/a/eVUkeET Would you be so kind and create a working Plunkr if it works for you? Thank you

Comment: You were right, it wasn't just the dot, it didn't work in Firefox, timeClass needs to be changed a little and then it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/eeYQVupQDopATsUluwx6?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! I have forked the plunk to use the relative units instead of the absolute ones